# Check user status as part of SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running an SQL query that shows a collection of vouchers, in order of how many times the voucher has been used down to £0 in another database.

As a final step though, i'd like to check that the 'user.state' of the corresponding 'voucher_credits.user_id' is still 'active', how can I add this in?

```
SELECT vouchers.code, count(voucher_credits.voucher_id) as Activated
    FROM vouchers, voucher_credits, users
    WHERE vouchers.code LIKE '%sentme%' 
        AND vouchers.id = voucher_credits.voucher_id
        AND voucher_credits.remaining_credit = 0
        AND *** the user.state of voucher_credits.user is 'active' ***
    GROUP by vouchers.code
    ORDER by count(voucher_credits.voucher_id) DESC
    LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Please use ANSI join syntax (`INNER JOIN`). It'll make things vaguely readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like,

```
SELECT vouchers.code, count(voucher_credits.voucher_id) as Activated
FROM vouchers, voucher_credits, users
WHERE vouchers.code LIKE '%sentme%' 
    AND vouchers.id = voucher_credits.voucher_id
    AND voucher_credits.remaining_credit = 0
    AND users.id = voucher_credits.user_id AND user.state = 'active'
GROUP by vouchers.code
ORDER by count(voucher_credits.voucher_id) DESC
LIMIT 50
```